# Socket receive data

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a server that handles multiple clients.
I have clients that send and receive data by click event.
I want that whenever a client sends data, the server spreads it out to the other clients.

How can I make my clients listen to the server all the time?

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
       
    Dim outStream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text + "$")
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
    serverStream.Flush()

    Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)
    Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
    msg("Data from Server : " + returndata)
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a timer/thread to the client code and make it continuously poll the socket for inbound data and read it when present. Or, use `NetworkStream.ReadAsync()` instead and let it notify you when new data arrives. Either way, that does mean you will have to move your existing code that is reading the `inStream`, as it won't work in the `Click` event anymore if another timer/thread/async reads it first.

Comment: On a side note, when you do read in the `inStream`, you are ignoring the return value of `NetworkStream.Read()` to know how many bytes were actually received.  Passing the entire `inStream` to `GetString()` will produce garbage when the `inStream` is not entirely filled with data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i did this but it get into endless loop   ```            
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
        Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)
        Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
        TextBox1.Text = returndata

    End Sub ```

Comment: it is supposed to, as it is in a timer. Start the timer when the connection is opened, stop the timer when the connection is closed. Though, I do suggest using a thread or async task than a timer. Also, you are still ignoring the return value of `Read()`